# Flask login_user doesn't work with pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-login

I'm new to Pytest. I want to test my views which require login (decorated with `@login_required`).
I have following test function:

```
def test_add_new_post(self, client, user):
    login_user(user)
    assert current_user == user
    data = {
        'title': 'This is test post',
        'body': 'This is test body'
    }
    client.post(url_for('posts.add_new'), data=data)
    assert Post.query.count() == 1
```

where the `client` is:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def client(request, app):
    return app.test_client()
```

The `assert current_user == user` returns `True`, but the `client.post` returns the login page, because the `login_required` redirects to a login page. Why is this happening and what is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me (based on [this comment](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-flask/issues/40#issuecomment-447061393)):

```py
def test_with_authenticated_user(app):
    @app.login_manager.request_loader
    def load_user_from_request(request):
        return User.query.first()
    # now you can call client.post or similar methods
```

Answer (score 4):

perhaps not the most streamlined way, but: "It can be convenient to globally turn off authentication when unit testing. To enable this, if either of the application configuration variables LOGIN_DISABLED or TESTING is set to True, this decorator will be ignored." via https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was modifying the `client` fixture so that you log in the user and return the client inside of a context.

For example, in your `conftest.py` file:

```py
from app.models import User # change according to where your User class is
from flask_login import login_user

@pytest.fixture(module='session')
def client(app):
    with app.test_request_context():
        user = User(name='test', email='test@example.com', ...)
        login_user(user)
        yield app.test_client()
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who landed here trying to test routes that require user login: sending a POST request to the login route before running the actual test worked for me:

```
import pytest
from your_project import app, current_user, login_manager

# Configure app
app.config.update({"TESTING": True})  # Set TESTING to True
app.config.update({"WTF_CSRF_ENABLED": False})  # Set csrf token to False
app.config.update({"LOGIN_DISABLED": True})  # Disable login

# Initiate login_manager
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login"

# Mock user loader
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
        
def test_foo():
    # Use app context
    with app.test_client() as client: 
        # First, login the user via the `/login` route
        response = client.post('/login', data={
            'username': TESTUSER,
            'password': TESTPASSWORD
        }, follow_redirects=True)

        # Check if the login was successful
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert current_user.is_authenticated
        
        # Test the POST request for the `/foo` route
        response = client.get(path='/foo', 
                              follow_redirects=False)
    # Assert the server responded OK status
    assert response.status_code == 200
    # Add further tests specific to the `/foo` route
```

Granted, this does not fix the `login_user()` issue but for me the latter just didn't work with my code - even after three hours of trying and fixing various parts. In the end, all I needed was to have a mock logged-in user and the code above solved it.